# parsing a xml file with linq

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have following xml structure:

```
 //this is the root
<factory ver="123" id="1">
    //can be a lot of lines
   <line id="123" name="line name">
         //can be alot of machines
         <machine id="101" Type="Weel">
           <setting Title="Filled" Value="No"  />
           <setting Title="Size"   Value="14" />
           <setting Title="Mandatory" Value="No"/>
        </machine>
        <machine id="222" Type="Reel">
           <setting Title="Filled" Value="No"  />
           <setting Title="Size"   Value="14" />
           <setting Title="Mandatory" Value="No"/>
        </machine>
   </line>
  <line id="312" name="line name1">
         <machine id="111" Type="Weel">
           <setting Title="Filled" Value="No"  />
           <setting Title="Size"   Value="14" />
           <setting Title="Mandatory" Value="No"/>
        </machine>
        <machine id="333" Type="Reel">
           <setting Title="Filled" Value="No"  />
           <setting Title="Size"   Value="14" />
           <setting Title="Mandatory" Value="No"/>
        </machine>
```

How I can via `Linq`  and `XDocument` by given machine ID to get it's type and all it's settings(there can be much more not listed all of them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can get to a particular machine easily like this:

```
var element = doc.Descendants("machine")
                 .FirstOrDefault(x => (int) x.Attribute("id") == targetId);
```

That will return `null` if there are no matching elements.

If you want to go from that to a dictionary of setting name to setting value, you can use:

```
// After checking whether `element` is null of course
var settings = element.Elements("setting")
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("Title").Value,
                                    x => x.Attribute("Value").Value);
```

And the type is simple:

```
var type = (string) element.Attribute("Type");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
XElement.Parse(...).Descendants("machine").First(m => m.Attribute("id").Value == x)
```